# I have a question about dealing polynomials using matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, let's say we find a constant function that is closest to $y=x^4$ on the interval $0\leq x\leq1$. Then we solve matrix

$ \begin{bmatrix}(1,1) & (1,x)\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}C \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}= $  $\begin{bmatrix}(1,x^4) \end{bmatrix}$

and integrate $(1,1)=\int _{0}^{1}dx=1$ and $(1,x^4)=\int _{0}^{1}x^{4}dx=\dfrac{1}{5}.$ Thus we get $C=\dfrac{1}{5}$

That's how I was instructed to do routinely without understanding.
I want to know what the ordered pairs $(1,1)$ $(1,x)$ actually mean in that matrix and why we are integrating on the interval and why $(1,1)$ equals to $\int _{0}^{1}dx$ and $(1,x^4)$ to $\int _{0}^{1}x^{4}dx$.

Not only that, it seems to me they use the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} (1,1) & (1,x)&\dots \\(x,1)&(x,x)&\dots\\(x^2,1)&(x^2,x)&\dots\\ \vdots & \vdots \end{bmatrix}$ when they deal with such polynomials problems. Where did that matrix come from and how? Why did they construct that matrix with such ordered pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A comment**: you don't need a $1\times 2$ matrix, $1\times 1$ will do:
$$
[\langle 1,1\rangle][C]=[\langle 1,x^4\rangle]
$$
has all the information you need.

**The setup.** To start with we have to know what "closest" means, that is we need to say what we mean by the distance between two functions $f,g$ both defined on $[0,1]$. We have an inner product defined on the space of functions, namely $\langle f,g\rangle:=\int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x)dx.$ The square of the distance between $f$ and $g$ is defined as $\langle f-g,f-g\rangle$, which simplifies to $\langle f,f\rangle -2\langle f,g\rangle+\langle g,g\rangle$. (This is just like the cosine rule when we are dealing with ordinary vectors.)

**Constant Function.** We want to find a constant function $x\mapsto C$ which is closest to the function  $x\mapsto x^4$.

The square of the distance  between these functions is $C^2 \langle 1,1\rangle -2C \langle 1,x^4\rangle +\langle x^4,x^4\rangle$. For a minimum we must find the derivative and equate it to $0$, that is we need to solve $2C\langle 1,1\rangle -2C \langle 1,x^4\rangle=0$. This gives $C=\frac{\langle 1,x^4\rangle}{\langle 1,1\rangle}=\frac{1}{5}$ as you know.

**Linear Function.** Now suppose we wanted to find the linear function $x\mapsto A+Bx$ closest to $x^4$.

The distance squared is $\langle A+Bx, A+Bx\rangle -2\langle A+Bx,x^4\rangle -\langle x^4,x^4\rangle.$ If we crunch this out we see it is equal to
$$
A^2\langle 1,1\rangle 
+2AB\langle 1,x\rangle
+B^2 \langle x,x\rangle
-2A\langle 1,x^4\rangle
-2B\langle x,x^4\rangle
+\langle x^4,x^4\rangle.
$$

This time we need to differentiate with respect to $A$ and to $B$ and set both equal to $0$. This gives us two equations, and (after we do the calculation) we can write it in matrix terms
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\langle 1,1\rangle & \langle x,1\rangle\\
\langle 1,x\rangle & \langle x,x\rangle\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}A \\ B \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}\langle 1,x^4\rangle \\ \langle x,x^5\rangle\end{bmatrix}
$$

**The general case.**  All this can be generalised but I am going to leave that for you to explore.